# Use of box-generating characters (utf-8) in PDFBox

Tags: java, utf-8, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am currently stuck on the following problem: Generating a document with PDFBox I would like to include the box-generating characters, preferably of Courier New. For those of you, who shouldn't know what the bgcs are, here is a picture of them:

[image: BGFs]

In my Java-Class I currently got the following lines.

```
contentStream.setFont(PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, "pdf_content/cour.ttf") , 12);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.drawString("┼┌┐└┘│─┘├┤┬┴┼");
contentStream.endText();
```

Unfortunately, as one can see in the output, they result in some weird characters and not the desired bars.

[image: Weird output in the PDF]

Did anyone encounter the same problem or has any solution to this problem? I might also mention that printing characters like german "Umlaute" ("äöüß") works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a bug, essentially the same as with the € (EURO) symbol, cf [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22274334/1729265). Essentially you need a replacement for the `PDPageContentStream` method `drawString`.

Comment: thanks! good to know this is a bug, apache didn't show anything about that..

Comment: Check that your IDE is set to UTF-8 (editor _and_ comnpiler). Could test it with `"\u2500\u2502\u250c..."` or read the codes in those "[]" char blocks.

Answer (score 0):

By exporting the subset of the needed characters to a new font and mapping them to unicode `0041` to `004e` and `0061` to `006e` enables you to work with these characters using keys A-Z and a-n. PDFBox enables you to include the font externally by using the following code:

```
contentStream.setFont( PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, "pdf_content/bgcs.ttf"), 12);
```

Since I have been searching for a free and although working program to edit existing fonts, I found that fontforge and Type Light both seem to understand working with character mappings (tested with Type Light, since fontforge is more of the linux/unix application hard to embed in Windows 8.1).

Hope this helps anybody stumbling over this bug of the drawString method.