# Write arabic characters with PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

1. Update 1

I'm trying to write some Arabic characters in a pdf document using pdfbox.  As a result I get some strange characters.  You can find below the code snippet I used for my test.  Notice that the same code was used to print Latin characters without any problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
    document.addPage(page);

    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,true, true);

    //Use of a unicode font
    PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document,"C:/arialuni.ttf");

    font.setFontEncoding(new WinAnsiEncoding());

    stream.setFont(font, 12);
    stream.beginText();

    stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(40, 600);

    stream.drawString("سي ججس ححسيب حسججسيبنم حح ");
    stream.endText();
    stream.close();
    document.save("c:\\resultpdf.pdf");
    document.close();

}
```

Thanks for your help.  I tried a Unicode font downloaded from Microsoft website ,but I still have the same result.

2. Update 2

By using the method 'drawUnicodeString' and the mehod 'loadTTF' I got form the [PDFBOX-922](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-922)
I was able to write arabic charactersm but they are disconnected and ordered from left-to-right.  Here are the two methods 'drawUnicodeString' and 'loadTTF'

```
public void drawUnicodeString(String text) throws IOException {
    COSString string = new COSString();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        string.append(c >> 8);
        string.append(c & 0xff);
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    string.writePDF(buffer);
    appendRawCommands(buffer.toByteArray());
    appendRawCommands(32);
    appendRawCommands(getISOBytes("Tj\n"));
}


public static PDType0Font loadTTF(PDDocument doc, InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
    /* Load the font which we will convert to Type0 font. */
    PDTrueTypeFont pdTtf = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, is);

    TrueTypeFont ttf = pdTtf.getTTFFont();
    CMAPEncodingEntry unicodeMap = null;
    for (CMAPEncodingEntry candidate : ttf.getCMAP().getCmaps()) {
        if (candidate.getPlatformId() == CMAPTable.PLATFORM_WINDOWS
                && candidate.getPlatformEncodingId() == CMAPTable.ENCODING_UNICODE) {
            unicodeMap = candidate;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (unicodeMap == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "To use as CIDFont, the TTF must have a Windows platform Unicode encoding");
    }
    float scaling = 1000f / ttf.getHeader().getUnitsPerEm();

    MyPDCIDFontType2Font pdCidFont2 = new MyPDCIDFontType2Font();
    pdCidFont2.setBaseFont(pdTtf.getBaseFont());
    pdCidFont2.setFontDescriptor((PDFontDescriptorDictionary) pdTtf
            .getFontDescriptor());
    /* Fixme -- should determine the minimum and maximum charcode in the map */
    int[] cid2gid = new int[65536];
    List<Float> widths = new ArrayList<Float>();
    int[] widthValues = ttf.getHorizontalMetrics().getAdvanceWidth();
    for (int i = 0; i < cid2gid.length; i++) {
        int glyph = unicodeMap.getGlyphId(i);
        cid2gid[i] = glyph;
        widths.add((float) i);
        widths.add((float) i);
        widths.add(widthValues[glyph] * scaling);
    }
    pdCidFont2.setCidToGid(cid2gid);
    pdCidFont2.setWidths(widths);
    pdCidFont2.setDefaultWidth(widths.get(0).longValue());

    /* Now construct the type0 font that we actually return */
    myType0Font pdFont0 = new myType0Font();
    pdFont0.setDescendantFont(pdCidFont2);
    pdFont0.setDescendantFonts(new COSObject(pdCidFont2.getCOSObject()));
    pdFont0.setEncoding(COSName.IDENTITY_H);

    pdFont0.setBaseFont(pdTtf.getBaseFont());

    // pdfont0.setToUnicode(COSName.IDENTITY_H); XXX how to express identity
    // mapping as ToUnicode program? */
    return pdFont0;
}
```

and here are the characters printed :

[image: disconnected arabic letters]

I don't know why these characters are disconnected

Comment: I am not familiar with PDFBox, but I think the problem is on the line: `font.setFontEncoding( new WinAnsiEncoding() ); ` Set unicode encoding instead of ansi encoding.

Comment: Try to use every `Encoding` implementation from this document: http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/encoding/Encoding.html

Comment: Two problems. **1)** `PDPageContentStream.drawString()` does not properly handle any Unicode character with a code point beyond 255, cf. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22274334/1729265) where strange characters appear for the € EURO symbol; **2)** (as mentioned by @Rafael) `WinAnsiEncoding` does not include Arabic characters.

Comment: for the encoding i tried the following list ; but i still have the same result   :       PdfDocEncoding pdfDocEncoding = new PdfDocEncoding();
WinAnsiEncoding winAnsiEncoding = new WinAnsiEncoding();
PdfDocEncoding pdfEncode = new PdfDocEncoding();
StandardEncoding standardEncoding = new StandardEncoding();
Type1Encoding t1 = new Type1Encoding(128);
WinAnsiEncoding en = new WinAnsiEncoding();

Comment: In the example here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260344/pdfbox-encode-symbol-currency-euro/22274334#22274334) ; they put "byte[] commands = "(x) Tj ".getBytes();" .where the value "(x) Tj" was gotten from ?

Comment: They are "disconnected" because you are using the isolated forms. Converting isolated form to the proper initial, medial, and final forms is (apparently) not a function in PDFBox, so you have to do this some other way. They are "not in order" means, they are left-to-right instead of the other way around? Again, probably interpreting the Unicode RTL indicator is not in PDFBox, so (again) do it yourself, or find a library that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arabic can be written by applying both [PDFBOX-922](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-922) and [PDFBOX-1287](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1287) .(the diff files are attached to in issues description)
I hope that the patches will be applied in the version 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

i suggest you try adding ICU4J jars to your project :
[ICU4J](https://pdfbox.apache.org/dependencies.html)

Comment: I added the Jars to my project but this doesn't resolve the problem