# How to draw text containing characters like € in PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfbox

I have a text to draw on pdf, something like `500 €/hour`. I am using [PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android) library.

I was trying to write above string as follows,

```
pageContentStream.drawString("500 " + Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.euro)).toString() + "/hour");
```

where `euro` is defined in `strings.xml` as

```
<string name="euro">(&#8364;)</string>
<string name="pound">(&#163;)</string>
```

With above code `PdfBox-Android`is writing some gibberish characters.

I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274334) to write `€` using pdfbox, which is working perfectly.

My question is how to write the text next to `€` sign in one go..?

Do I need to write `€` first, then move text next to it and then write remaining text? I don't feel that would be a `correct` solution.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer you refer to, *PDFBox's String encoding is far from perfect yet (version 1.8.x)*. This actually is a nice way to say **it is broken**.. If you use PDFBox 1.8.* (or older), characters with Unicode codes beyond 255 can only be displayed using customized methods, not PDFBox' `PDPageContentStream.drawString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260344/pdfbox-encode-symbol-currency-euro/22274334#22274334) I manage to implement what I needed. Please refer following code snippet.

```
contentStream.beginText();

/*x will act as placeholder here*/
byte[] commands = "(500 x/year**) Tj ".getBytes();

/* commands[index_of_x] = (byte)128, where 128 is decimal value of octal
 * 200. (char code for '€' in WinAnsiEncoding).
 * you may want to refer annex D.2, Latin Character Set and Encodings of 
 * PDF specification ISO 32000-1
 */
commands[5] = (byte) 128;

contentStream.appendRawCommands(commands);
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
```

PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the HTML code of the currency symbol

```
Html.fromHtml((String) currency_symbol).toString()

Html.fromHtml((String) "&#8364;").toString() //for euro

Html.fromHtml((String) "&#163;").toString()  //for pound
```

Comment: @Rupesh: you shouldn't just *'Accept'* this answer, but also *'Upvote'* it!

Comment: pardon me.. I am reverting it.. I tried above solution with `£` and that worked.. but its not working for `€` and other characters...

Comment: What code are you using?? Refer this http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp cause I tried its working fine

Comment: @WISHY same as yours.. but the thing is I am drawing text on `pdf`. `PageContentStream`is still drawing garbage characters with above method..

Comment: @Rupesh have look at this if it solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260344/pdfbox-encode-symbol-currency-euro