# U+0413 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, pdfbox, acrofields

I have a PDF with a textField with the name "lastname" and I want to fill it with this value:
`Горохова`

Using PDFBox version 2.0.30 and java.

Here is my code:

```
public void fillDocument() throws IOException {
    // Create a new document with an empty page.
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("InputPdf.pdf"));
    PDFont formFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, Myclass.class.getResourceAsStream(
        "/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/ttf/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"), false);
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    final PDResources resources = new PDResources();
    acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
    final String fontName = resources.add(formFont).getName();
    String defaultAppearanceString = "/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g"; // adjust to replace existing font name

    acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
    acroForm.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
    PDTextField textField = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("lastName");
    textField.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
    textField.setValue("Горохова");
    doc.save("output.pdf");
}
```

But when it tries to set the value, it failed with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0413 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.encode(PDTrueTypeFont.java:398)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:337)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getStringWidth(PDFont.java:368)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PlainTextFormatter.format(PlainTextFormatter.java:195)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.insertGeneratedAppearance(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:567)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceContent(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:424)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceValue(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:248)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:264)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:227)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:219)
```

The fun fact is if I add a new page in the existing pdf with a PDTextField and the same value, it works.

Comment: Can you share the input file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDFBox U+00A0 is not available in this font's encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470158/pdfbox-u00a0-is-not-available-in-this-fonts-encoding)

Comment: @seenukarthi as you can see the code use is the same as your answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the code looks correct and is also similar to the `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` example. For some reason it seems that PDFBox doesn't "know" about the modified font, because the new font does not have WinAnsiEncoding.

Comment: Are you *sure* there are no previous exceptions when loading the font?

Comment: yes, the exception is only when the value is set, if i set a differet value like "ok" it works

Comment: If you can't share the file because it is confidential, try reproducing the effect with a public PDF, e.g. a tax form.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19axUjzb3XP0tE-404UHkqX-RMhbBvJTT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here a similar file with same issue

Comment: You won't believe it, but it worked immediately for me.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bzWIMtNkLdM0K7cB0ljUjuB6esQbzs--/view?usp=sharing

Comment: my bad, I have accidentaly removed the line textField.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString); infact now it works for me in this pdf. In the other pdf no, maybe is because there is already a value on the field, I will try to delete it or to recreate the field and i will let you know